# git config - Add option when key contains double quotes

Tags: git, gerrit, git-config

Is there a way to add a configuration option with `git config` when there are double quotes in the key?

In Gerrit there is an option `commentlink "jira"` as the key ([more information](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#commentlink)). No matter what I try, escaping the space and double quotes, use single quotes etc, nothing works. No matter what I try the result is (or similar):

```
error: invalid key: commentlink "jira".match
```

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation, the command should be:

```
git config -f <filename> "commentlink.jira.match" '([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)'
```

On disk this will be written as:

```
[commentlink "jira"]
        match = ([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)
```